# How to use emmprep on an unbalanced nested rma.mv meta-analysis model in R?

Tags: r, emmeans, metafor

I would love to use `emmeans` with a complicated model from `rma.mv()` in `metafor`, and for this there is the function `emmprep()`. However, the model I have is unbalanced and nested, leading to redundant predictors being dropped from the model due to rank deficiencies. In this case, `emmprep()` does not work. As per the helpfile: "In this case, one should remove any redundancies in the original model fitted before using this function."

How do I do that? Do I have to use dummy variables to avoid rank deficiencies, or is there a simpler solution?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(metafor)

dat <- dat.bcg #take some example data to modify

#modify to make it work for this example (so now we have two factors)
dat$ablat<-c("a","b","c","a","b","b","a","b","c","a","b","c","a")

#get the yis & vis
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat,
              slab=paste0(author, ", ", year)) 

#run a nested model
res4 <- rma.mv(yi, vi, mods = ~ alloc/ablat, data=dat) 
res4
 
library(emmeans) #load emmeans
sav <- emmprep(res4) #this returns the redundant predictors error

#"Error in emmprep(res4) : 
#    Cannot use function when some redundant predictors were dropped from the model."
```

(PS. I asked this question badly before and have deleted that version to avoid confusion)

Comment: Is it an actual error, as in not returning a result at all? If not, maybe it would work to do `sav1 <- update(sav, nesting = "ablat %in% alloc")`

Comment: It is an actual error not returning a result (```Error in emmprep(res4): Cannot use function when some redundant predictors were dropped from the model```) so unfortunately your suggestion doesn't work...

Comment: Maybe communicate with the **metafor** developer and suggest that it be re-engineered. The **emmeans** code does support rank deficiency better than a lot of packages. I will check to ensure that the `qdrg()` function doesn't create barriers.

Comment: Righto - thanks for the advice! (and yes emmeans is usually wonderfully flexible with all sorts of models - your efforts there are much appreciated)

Comment: Did you try `emmprep(res4, nesting = "ablat %in% alloc")`? The documentation says that `...` is passed to `qdrg`, and that in turn would be passed to `ref_grid`. So there is hope that it works.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I just tried it, and same error as before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible workaround

It seems you don't really need `emmprep()` all that much. The `qdrg()` function in **emmeans** almost works out-of-the-box. The only hitch is that `rma` models name the intercept `intrcpt` instead of `(Intercept)`, and we have to fix that. Here's an example with a dataset I created for the [feature request](https://github.com/wviechtb/metafor/issues/74) I posted on **metafor**'s GitHub site

```r
library(metafor)
## Loading required package: Matrix
## Loading required package: metadat
## Loading required package: numDeriv
## 
## Loading the 'metafor' package (version 4.2-0). For an
## introduction to the package please type: help(metafor)
library(emmeans)

dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
dat <- transform(dat,
                 acat = factor(ablat < 40, labels = c("high", "low")),
                 era = factor(1+as.integer((year-1940)/15), 
                              labels = c("early","mid","late")))

with(dat, table(acat, era))   # there's an empty cell
##       era
## acat   early mid late
##   high     3   2    1
##   low      0   2    5

mod <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ acat * era, data = dat)
## Warning: Redundant predictors dropped from the model.

emmprep(mod)   # fails
## Error in emmprep(mod): Cannot use function when some redundant predictors were dropped from the model.

# However ...
rownames(mod$beta)[1] = "(Intercept)"
RG = qdrg(object = mod)   # named argument 'object' is essential
RG
## 'emmGrid' object with variables:
##     acat = high, low
##     era = early, mid, late
## Some things are non-estimable (null space dim = 1)

emmeans(RG, ~era | acat)
## acat = high:
##  era   emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  early -0.971 0.244  8   -1.533   -0.409
##  mid   -1.366 0.347  8   -2.166   -0.566
##  late  -1.442 0.325  8   -2.190   -0.693
## 
## acat = low:
##  era   emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  early nonEst    NA NA       NA       NA
##  mid   -0.299 0.340  8   -1.082    0.485
##  late  -0.268 0.161  8   -0.641    0.104
## 
## Confidence level used: 0.95
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you for persevering with that - your work-around works on the made-up example in my original question, and also on the more complicated models I am actually working with.